# What are the types of noise (FM,AM, MSK modulated) that I can use for jamming GSM signals?

Tags: digital-communications, electronic-warfare

I need to jam GSM signals in-order to prevent mobiles in near-by vicinity from connecting to the BTS. I am employing a noise based jamming strategy. What type of noise will be most appropriate for this task?

Comment: Those who know the answer are prohibited from answering this question, while those who have no idea whatsoever are not prohibited from giving any answer that their mind comes up with at 3 a.m. preferably expressed in 140 of fewer ASCII characters.

Comment: A few years ago LadyYada created the [WaveBubble](http://www.ladyada.net/make/wavebubble/index.html) programmable GSM jammer. There are links and notes and many hints to what to google for.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any kind on in-band interference (like Gaussian noise) will mess up the GSM signal and prevent its correct reception. Note, however, that:

- Transmitting on the GSM band without a license is illegal in many locations.
- Tampering with cell phone operation in general is also illegal.

If you insist on doing this, one approach would be to set up a GSM base station using OpenBTS in an environment where your signals won't interfere with other base stations and won't be otherwise detected (for example in a laboratory with RF shielding). You can use unlocked phones to connect to your OpenBTS base station, and then measure the effect of your interefernce on their performance.